# number of groups in a polars groupby

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, python-polars

For a polars groupby object, what is the equivalent of the pandas `ngroups` attribute on a pandas groupby object? Or in any case, what is the idiomatic what to get the number of groups in a polars groupby object?

Comment: I think you may need to compute something and then get the height e.g. `.count().height` or maybe [`.agg_groups`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.agg_groups.html#polars.Expr.agg_groups) - depending on what you want to do with the number.

Comment: @jqurious Yeah that's what I'm doing, but surely there's something more idiomatic??

Comment: I'm not sure. The groupby is "lazy" so the number can't be available until something is computed - or at least that is how I understand things. If you just want the number - you could perhaps use `df.unique()` instead of groupby.

Comment: @jqurious I've settled on applying `Series.n_unique` to the column I'm grouping on, but I've also filed an [enhancement request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7571).

Comment: Thanks for the update. My understanding is with `g = df.groupby(...)` polars doesn't actually do anything - you get a groupby object back immediately - similar to declaring a generator in Python. It is not until you "consume" the groupby that the number of groups would be known - which is why it cannot have an `.ngroups` attribute. What are you using the number for? Maybe there is an alternative approach.

Comment: @jqurious I'm hoping they have a clever cheap way to compute it as a property, but yes, the request might be rejected as inadequately lazy. The need arose when I was plotting (with Matplotlib) multiple axes in a figure and needed as many axes as there were groups. Using `n_unique` (see above) is currently meeting my needs (but feels a bit hackish).

Answer (score 2):

A polars `groupby` object is lazy. It has not computed anything yet. You have to materialize it with an `.agg` call.

If you wan to have the number of groups, I'd recommend calling `n_unique`.

```py
pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    "b": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
}).select(
    pl.struct(["a", "b"]).n_unique()
).item()
```